# Replacing Spaces With "%20" - String Subscript Out Of Range

Tags: c++, string

I'm going through a coding interview book and got stuck on a question: **Replace all spaces in a string with '%20'**.

I tried running this solution in my compiler but got this error: String Subscript Out Of Range. So, I looked up stackoverflow for that error and got a solution to try to append new chars with += instead of just assigning new chars to the string but that still produced the same error.

Here's my code. Thanks so much for your time!

```
void replaceSpaces(string &str)
{
    int spaces = 0;

    // Count number of spaces in original string
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            spaces++;
    }

    // Calculate new string size
    int newSize = str.size() + (2 * spaces);
    str.resize(newSize); // thanks Vlad from Moscow

    // Copy the chars backwards and insert '%20' where needed
    for (int i = str.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            str[newSize - 1] = '0'; // += '0' didnt work
            str[newSize - 2] = '2'; // += didnt work
            str[newSize - 3] = '%'; // same
            newSize = newSize - 3;
        }
        else
        {
            str[newSize - 1] = str[i]; // same
            newSize--;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string test = "sophisticated ignorance, write my curses in cursive";
    replaceSpaces(test);
    cout << test << endl;
}
```

Comment: Which line gives the out-of-range error? When you were stepping through your code in a debugger, what were the variables' values right before this happened?

Comment: Why don't you use `STL` string find and replace?

Comment: because of educational purposes

Comment: *So, I looked up stackoverflow for that error*  The error is self-explanatory enough to not need being looked up.  What you should have been doing is debugging your code to see where you are indexing beyond the boundaries of your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not resize string `str`.

You set variable `newSize`

```
int newSize = str.size() + (2 * spaces);
```

larger than `str.size()` and use it like an index in `str`

```
str[newSize - 1] = str[i];
```

At least you could write at first

```
str.resize( newSize );
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string & replaceSpaces( std::string &s )
{
    std::string::size_type spaces = 0;

    // Count number of spaces in original string
    for ( char c : s ) if ( c == ' ' ) ++spaces;

    if ( spaces != 0 )
    {
        auto i = s.size();
        // Calculate new string size
        auto j = s.size() + 2 * spaces;
        s.resize( j );

        // Copy the chars backwards and insert '%20' where needed
        while ( i != j )
        {
            if ( s[--i] == ' ' )
            {
                s[--j] = '0';
                s[--j] = '2';
                s[--j] = '%';
            }
            else
            {
                s[--j] = s[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return s;
}    

int main()
{
    std::string test = "sophisticated ignorance, write my curses in cursive";

    std::cout << "\"" << test << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "\"" << replaceSpaces( test ) << "\"\n";
}
```

The program output is

```
"sophisticated ignorance, write my curses in cursive"
"sophisticated%20ignorance,%20write%20my%20curses%20in%20cursive"
```

**EDIT:** After you inserted a statement with `resize` as I adviced then in the loop

```
for (int i = str.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

variable `i` must be initialized with the old size of the string that it had before resizing it.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Tried str.resize( newSize ); but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a practical solution without being overly concerned with performance, here's something much simpler:

```
void replaceSpaces(string &str) {
  str = std::regex_replace(str, std::regex(" "), "%20");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::string replaceSpaces(std::string str)
{
    std::string newStr;
    for (char c : str)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
            newStr.append("%20");
        else
            newStr.push_back(c);
    }
    return newStr;
}

int main()
{
   std::string test = "sophisticated ignorance, write my curses in cursive";
   std::string newtest = replaceSpaces(test);
   std::cout << test << std::endl << newtest << std::endl;
}
```